# Perl module not found when script executed by php

Tags: php, perl, module, exec

I execute a perl script with `exec` via php, however I receive an error that the module Net::DNS is missing. I have installed the module as a regular user and as such is located in /home/user/perl5/i686-linux-thread-multi and I do use a full path (/usr/bin/perl) in the exec.

I've even tried to add the /home/user/perl5/i686-linux-thread-multi directory to @INC but the script still throws the error...

And I also tried to install the module with custom install path directly into /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl, but that didn't solve the problem either.
And symlink didn't fix that either.

Here is the error message

```
  Can't locate Net/DNS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl
```

Any idea how this can be solved, sort of running out of ideas how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before `exec`, add:

```
$ENV{PERL5LIB} = "$ENV{PERL5LIB}:/home/user/perl5/i686-linux-thread-multi";
```

Why using `use lib` wont work (for pavel's comment):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib "hate_you";
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(\@INC);

print "In sub process....\n";
exec(qq{perl -MData::Dumper -e "print Dumper(\@INC);"});
```

will print on my machine:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'hate_you',
          '/etc/perl',
          '/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2',
          '/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2',
          '/usr/lib/perl5',
          '/usr/share/perl5',
          '/usr/lib/perl/5.14',
          '/usr/share/perl/5.14',
          '/usr/local/lib/site_perl',
          '.'
        ];
In sub process....

    $VAR1 = '/etc/perl';
    $VAR2 = '/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2';
    $VAR3 = '/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2';
    $VAR4 = '/usr/lib/perl5';
    $VAR5 = '/usr/share/perl5';
    $VAR6 = '/usr/lib/perl/5.14';
    $VAR7 = '/usr/share/perl/5.14';
    $VAR8 = '/usr/local/lib/site_perl';
    $VAR9 = '.';
```

Comment: this refers to exec's from Perl, I believe there is a similar env in php

Answer (score 0):

an alternative would be to include your personal library in your script, so it is independent from the environment set:

```
use lib qw(/home/user/perl5/i686-linux-thread-multi);

use Net::DNS;
```

Comment: I doubt this will work, use lib modifies the @INC in the current process not other spawned (like exec) from the current one.

Comment: why wouldn't it work when used in the Perl program you `exec`? Never had problems with that...